# Is there a dplyr way to use REGEXP within a database query?

Tags: mysql, r, database, dplyr

When I'm querying a database with dplyr, I often need to search strings. Usually, I use `%like%` which works sufficiently. At times, though, I'd rather use regular expressions. If I was writing pure SQL, I'd write something like:

```
select pidm, jobtitle from people
where jobtitle REGEXP "^Athl.*train"
```

But of course, I'd like to write tidyverse-style R:

```
foo  <- tbl(my_database,"people") %>%
   filter(jobtitle %regexp% "^Athl.*train") %>%
   select(pidm, jobtitle )
```

Using `stringr::str_detect()` doesn't work in SQL. Is there a way to continue writing tidyverse-style code but still do regexp style searches?

If it matters, my database runs on MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's correct `dbplyr` does not support `stringr` commands, yet.  I have PR for that so we'll hopefully have that soon.  In the meanwhile, you can call a SQL native command, like `INSTR` from within `filter()`, so for instance you could do this:

```
foo  <- tbl(my_database,"people") %>%
           filter(instr("train", jobtitle)) > 0) %>%
           select(pidm, jobtitle )
```

Answer (score 2):

The newest release of [dbplyr](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/01/dbplyr-1-2/) 1.2.0 supports several stringr functions, including str_detect(). So, @wtmatthias answer now works.

```
flights_db %>% select(origin, flight) %>% filter(stringr::str_detect(origin, 'JF'))
```

Comment: Just a note that, as of June 6, 2018, `stringr::str_detect()` support existed in dbplyr, but at least for several databases including MySQL, it had a bug that reversed the arguments, so the pattern was used as the string to search within (see https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3397 ). This is fixed by https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/pull/81 in the development version which hasn't yet hit CRAN.

Comment: @crazybilly According to Hadley this function has never worked correctly and the function is no longer available in dbplyr 1.4.0 https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/295

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it seems like you might be using the "old" method for SQL querying w/in R. If you aren't already aware, **[dbplyr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=dbplyr)** is somewhat newly released and you will need to install (`install.packages("dbplyr")`) & load it with dplyr. You should be able to use `stringr::str_detect()` inside of `filter()` at that point. This [link](http://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dbplyr.html)  should give you all the info you need for how `dbplyr` works w/ dplyr and allows for more of the tidyverse-style we're used to. There's a note on MySQL as well in the link.

A simple example:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dbplyr)

nycflights13_sqlite(path = "path/for/sqlite")
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = "path/for/sqlite")
copy_to(con, nycflights13::flights, "flights")

DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT origin, flight 
            FROM flights WHERE origin like '%JF%'")

flights_db <- tbl(con, "flights")

flights_db %>% select(origin, flight) %>% filter(stringr::str_detect(origin, 'JF'))
```

Comment: Hm. I can't seem to get this to work with my database--I get similar errors when I try writing comparable code or even using your example against my server (I get an error:

    Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
      object 'origin' not found

Comment: I'm an idiot. Reproduced the same problem. I read a currently open PR as a committed when it's [not](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/pull/35). Looks like `stringr` still not supported w/ `dplyr` under current version. (Although based on that PR looks like it could be close). Sorry! Gonna delete answer since it's irrelevant.